# search for words that don't start at the the beginning of a line

Tags: regex

I only know how to start at the beginning of a line. But I want to exclude the beginning.
To be more concrete.

I want to search for the word import. But I don't want things like:

```
import java.util.*;
```

As expected this does not work: `^^` for excluding a line start.

Also in a character class `^` has a different meaning so no luck there.

So what would be a good way?

Comment: If the word doesn't start at the beginning of a line, wouldn't that imply that there's _some_ character, _any_ character, prior to the word?

Comment: Can't you just do `myString = myString.substring(1)`. This will cut off the first character. Then you can do your search, since the line will now read `mport java.util.*;`, it shouldn't match the first `import`.

Comment: @icemanind I do the search in a text editor, not with java.

Comment: @WilliamPrice damn, I was thinking to complicated :) Regex is kind of new for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This says "Find me import at the beginning of the line".

```
^import
```

So what you're wanting is any line with "import" but there is something else in front of it, right?

```
^.+import
```

Answer (score 2):

@AndyLester I don't have enough rep to comment on your answer yet but **it allows for the string to begin with "import" as long as import is found again in that same string**. Using .+ allows for any characters besides newline to come first... including the char sequence "import". So depends what the OP wants to determine if that is a "feature" or "bug"... @clankill3r which takes precedence for your problem 1) not starting with import or 2) containing import somewhere else in the string besides at the start

I think that what you should look to use is a negative lookahead - explained [here](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Looking_Ahead_and_Behind.html)

To check a string does not start with "import" using regex:

`^(?!import)`

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/_ps7Ce_5h4n-NTV2)

To check that a string does not start with "import" but does contain "import":

```
   ^(?!import).*(import).*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/lQN6lDkadb54vWLJ)

Answer (score 0):

```
(?!^)\bimport\b
```

Try this.This will not find `import` which is at the beginning.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/gQ3kS4/1